# How to run data.sql script when first run spring boot application in a new environment?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

As we know `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` configuration can generate database tables automate when we run the application in a new environment and `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` can run some scripts like a data.sql file in classpath after generating tables in the database.

here comes the question, how can we run the data.sql script under the configuration `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`?

or is there any other solution when we want to init some data in the database after we deploy the application in a new environment?

Answer (score 0):

data.sql is a Spring Boot mechanism and has nothing to do with Hibernate.

If you set `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` the script is executed:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

You could use some stored procedure code to initialize the database in the data.sql.

Another approach could be to listen for ApplicationReadyEvent and then to initalize the database.

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
    // Initalize the database
}
```

Comment: from my practice, only when configure as
`spring.datasource.initialize=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`
the data.sql can be init when first boot applicaion, but you must configure to 
`spring.datasource.initialize=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`
when reboot the application, or it will fail on start up.